# Android sqlite database update?

Tags: android, ios, database, sqlite

I am programming an app that will store a database locally and would like it to be able to update the database from a remote online database when changes have been made. I do not need to be able to write back to the remote database from the app. I am also trying to keep porting to IOS an option. How do i do this? thanks

Comment: There should be very few differences between Android and iOS when it comes to SQLite database structure, so I wouldn't worry about portability when designing your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very general question, so the best I can do is give you a general answer. You can do this quite easily. Just use an [HttpUrlConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) on your android app to pull data from the server and then update your database on the phone with the data you got from the server. If you want to get really fancy you can use a SyncAdapter, but that might be overkill for you needs.